# Synonym privilege issue in oracle after creation?

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, privileges, synonym

I have a parent table in schema A, when I try to select the synonym from schema B then it gives me error 'ORA-01031: insufficient privileges'. Please suggest what is the issue here? patrent table is in schema A and my synonym is in schema B.

Comment: Does schema B have select privileges on the table in schema A?

Comment: You have contradicting statements - `I have a synonym in schema A` and `my synonym is in schema B`

Comment: You'll get the fastest answer to your question if you provide the `CREATE` statements of the synonym, the object/table it is pointing to and the `GRANT` statements...

Comment: how can i check that? Please tell I am new to oracle and also if yes then how can I grants that privilege

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just creating the synonym doesn't grant any privilege on the underlying object. You need to explicitly grant required privileges on the object. Also, privilege are actually not granted on a synonym, the actual grant is made on the object referred to by the synonym.

To grant select on the table, do:

```
GRANT SELECT ON table TO SCHEMA2; -- do this in SCHEMA1
```